# How to fix scroll issue for a sidebar or content?

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I have an angular application with tailwind css and I am trying to get the responsiveness fixed on it. I am making use of flex containers and whatever I try, I am unable to get the scrolling worked. It makes my content scroll to the very end (horizontally) with short header.

In app.html

```
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen">
 <app-header></app-header>
 <app-content></app-content>
</div>
```

In content.html

```
<div class="font-bold bg-gray-200 overflow-auto">
<div class="w-64 bg-red-500"> 
<p class="mt-5 mb-10">HELLO</p>
<p class="mt-5 mb-10">HELLO</p>
<p class="mt-5 mb-10">HELLO</p>
<p class="mt-5 mb-10">HELLO</p>
</div>
</div>
...
```

Now when this is rendered on the UI, I am expected the side bar will have a scroll bar of its own. But instead this happens. The sidebar gets a scroll bar but along with it the page has it too which scrolls because of the header being present.

[image]

BUT when I remove the content of content.html and paste it in app.html itself, I get the scroll at the correct place.
[image]

So using it inside a component changes how it gets rendered. Why does this happen and whats the best way to solve this?